# In John 13 did Christ reveal the betrayer Judas only to the disciple whom he loved?

Tags: john

(KJV) [John 13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2013&version=NIV;KJV;SBLGNT):21

> 21 When Jesus had thus said, he was troubled in spirit, and testified, and said, Verily, verily, I say unto you, that one of you shall betray me.   22 Then the disciples looked one on another, doubting of whom he spake.   23 Now there was leaning on Jesus' bosom one of his disciples, whom Jesus loved.   24 Simon Peter therefore beckoned to him, that he should ask who it should be of whom he spake.   25 He then lying on Jesus' breast saith unto him, Lord, who is it? 26 ***Jesus answered, He it is, to whom I shall give a sop, when I have dipped it***.   And when he had dipped the sop, he gave it to Judas Iscariot, the son of Simon.

(KJV) John 13:28

> 28 ***Now no man at the table knew for what intent he spake this unto him***.

Did Christ whisper to the disciple whom he loved or openly address the 12 disciples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like Jesus must have whispered this directly to John discreetly and that John did not think it was appropriate to tell everyone else. If Jesus had wanted everyone to know, He could have told everyone. On the contrary, He told Judas to go and do what he was going to do and to do it "quickly," which was both cryptic enough the keep the disciples in the dark and enough to let John know that he should keep quiet.

John had to trust that Jesus knew what He was doing. I always connect this exchange at the table with the fact that John was the only disciple to remain at the foot of the cross. As the youngest disciple, probably in his early teens, it seems John had a special bond with Jesus, who was more like a father figure or like a much older brother (33-to-14?) to him.

Comment: I never realzed the age difference - but that makes the scriptures and the interactions between John and Jesus make much more sense - he was basically the "youngest child". Where did you get the age details exactly ?